# kafka kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe returns no output for a consumer group

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

kafka version 1.1

`--list` can get the consumers group

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list --command-config config/client_security.properties
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0
console-consumer-23379
console-consumer-44846
console-consumer-75221
console-consumer-57833
yizhisec-traffic
console-consumer-91940
group1
```

can't get any information. **This consumer group id is generated by spark**.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0  --command-config config/client_security.properties
```

get nothing

```
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
```

But test other consumers work.

[image]

## update more detail

---

I use Structured Streaming kafka
[image]

and when I use **zookeeper** to query get error

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0  --command-config config/client_security.properties
```

get error

```
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).
Error: The consumer group 'spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0' does not exist.
```

Comment: what version of spark-streaming-kafka-* are you using?, old kafka client version (below 0.9) seems to store kafka offset on Zookeeper and not show in this.

Comment: Also, please try to copy-paste your commands/output instead of sharing a screenshot.

Comment: @TuyenLuong  I have updated my post

Comment: What is the output of `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list --command-config config/client_security.properties
` ? Note the `--new-consumer` flag.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous  same as without

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kafka-consumer-groups \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --describe \
  --group your_consumer_group_name
```

will return no output if the consumers in the consumer group have not committed any offsets.

---

If the output of

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --describe \
  --group spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0 \
  --command-config config/client_security.properties
```

and

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --new-consumer
  --describe \
  --group spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0 \
  --command-config config/client_security.properties
```

matches and the consumer group appears in both consumer groups list output, my guess is that your consumers inside the consumer group `spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0` have not committed any offsets and this is why no information appears using the *describe* command.

---

Make sure that your consumers inside `spark-kafka-source-fd469ba1-6ffa-43cb-8919-06c45ae56fd6--724816166-driver-0` commit their offsets succesfully (either manually or automatically).

Comment: I like that answer! Maybe also worth mentioning that Spark Structured Streaming usually does not commit offsets to Kafka but rather uses checkpoints as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations).